# Which of these expressions is greater?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

With $0 \le a \le 1$, $0 \le b \le 1$, $0 \le  c \le 1$, is it possible to see which of the following is greatest

```
 x=  2 a Sqrt[b^2 + c^2],  y = Sqrt[1 + 8 \b^2 c^2]
```

Comment: In what sense do you mean _greatest_ ? If you do: `x = 2 a Sqrt[b^2 + c^2];
y = Sqrt[1 + 8 b^2 c^2];
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, {0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1},
   x >= y], Reals]` then you get `False` and your also get `False` for `y>=x` so neither is  greater than the other everywhere in the cube formed by a,b,c

Comment: If you are looking for if the maximum of y is bigger than the maximum of x then yes, y achieves a larger maximum than x as maxx is $2\sqrt{2}$ but maxy is $3$. `maxx = First@
   Maximize[{x, 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1}, {a, b, c}];
maxy = First@
   Maximize[{y, 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1}, {a, b, 
     c}];`

Comment: Since both are nonnegative you might maximize and minimize the difference of their squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 functions. The definition region is given by: 0≤a≤1, 0≤b≤1,  0≤c≤1.  Now, it could be that the region of one function is above the region of the other, then you could say one function is greater than the other. However, in your case the regions overlap. Therefore you may e.g. ask if one is greater than the other for specific arguments. Or you could compare the max or min values e.t.c.

Anyway, in either case you need to calculate the range of the functions. These can be done as:

```
f1[a_, b_, c_] = 2 a Sqrt[b^2 + c^2];
FunctionRange[{f1[a, b, c], 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 
  0 <= c <= 1}, {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

[image]

This means the range contains all real numbers between 0 and 2 Sqrt[2].

And for the second function:

```
f2[b_, c_] = Sqrt[1 + 8/b^2 c^2];
FunctionRange[{f2[b, c], 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1}, {b, c}, Reals]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ImpliciRegion` shows the region with

`2 a Sqrt[b^2+c^2] >=Sqrt[ 1 + 8/b^2 c^2]`

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[2 a Sqrt[b^2+c^2] >=Sqrt[ 1 + 8/b^2 c^2]
,{{a, 0, 1}, {b , 0, 1}, {c , 0, 1}}]

Show[{Region[reg]}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[2 a Sqrt[b^2+c^2] >=Sqrt[ 1 + 8/b^2 c^2], 
{a, 0.001,1}, {b , 0.001, 1}, {c , 0.001, 1}]
```

only evaluates if you exclude `a=b=c=0`